# Extracting date from a long character string timestamp data in R

Tags: r, date

I have a tibble and there is a timestamp column with string values (YearMonthDay...) as listed in the table below. I need to convert these into date format (`Month-Day-Year`).
For example, the first cell value in the table below should translate to `10-03-2022`.
How Do I do it? I already tried mutating a new column with `as.Date` and `as.POSIXct` but it did not work. Please assist.

| createTimestamp |
| --- |
| 20221003173428Z |
| 20220714172442Z |
| 20230118010424Z |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `as.Date` and specify the date foramt:

```r
df <- data.frame(createTimestamp = c('20221003173428Z', '20220714172442Z', '20230118010424Z'))

df$date1 <- as.Date(df$createTimestamp, '%Y%m%d')
# [1] "2022-10-03" "2022-07-14" "2023-01-18"

class(df$date1)
# [1] "Date"
```

> For `as.Date`, character strings are processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored.

---

If you want to re-foramt a date, pass it to `strftime` or `foramt` and explicitly specify the foramt:

```r
df$date2 <- strftime(as.Date(df$createTimestamp, '%Y%m%d'), '%m-%d-%Y')
# [1] "10-03-2022" "07-14-2022" "01-18-2023"
```

Note that after reforamting, the dates are no longer a `Date` object. They will be coerced to character instead.

```r
class(df$date2)
# [1] "character"
```

Answer (score 1):

First extract the part of the string you want with substr() then you can format however you like. Here I used a as.Date() as you asked for a date but you can use as.PosiXct() as well

```
x='20221003173428Z'

out=substr(x,1,8) # Note that per Darren's answer this part is not necessary, but may be intuitive for understanding
out=format(as.Date(out,format = '%Y%m%d'),"%m-%d-%Y")
out
```

you can do the same thing for a dataframe column I just pulled out a single example from your image of data...

```
# won't run 
mydata$colname <- substr(mydata$colname,1,8) 
 mydata$colname<- format(as.Date(mydata$colname,format=format = '%Y%m%d'),"%m-%d-%Y")
```